# Is this plot typical of gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, data-visualization, visualization

I have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/data-visualization/info and it seems to me that maybe I can find an answer here... or maybe it is off-topic here too.

Is this plot typical of gnuplot?
[image]

Source: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.10405.pdf

Comment: What do you mean *Is this plot typical of gnuplot?* ? Gnuplot can produce graphics that look like that, but I'm not sure of the sense in which you use the word *typical*.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark "typical" for me means almost "out-of-the-box" or with little customization. Can you give me some hints on how to get a similar graph with gnuplot? The source paper is from a group oh physicists and that make me think about gnuplot or some "exotic" framework like ROOT https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROOT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Roland Smith said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61043508/11369382), `gnuplot` is quite customizable.
To help you see how customizable it is, see below a complete example which reproduces wanted plot.

```
reset
set encoding utf8
# ***** TERMINAL SETTINGS *****
set terminal wxt size 800,450 font "Consolas"
# ***** GENERAL SETTINGS *****
# tics, key, and border
set tics nomirror scale 1.5
unset key
set border 7
# linestyles
set style line 1 lc "black"
set style line 2 lc "red"
# margins
set lmargin screen 0.100
set rmargin screen 0.900
set bmargin screen 0.135
# xlabel, xrange, and (m)xtics
set xlabel "Time [sec]"
set xrange [0:2.2]
set xtics 0.2 tc ls 1
set mxtics 4
# ***** CREATING SOME DATA TO PLOT *****
# Gaussian function plus some noise
f(x,a,b,c) = a*exp(-(x-b)**2/(2*c**2)) + a*0.02*rand(0)
# Storing on datablock
# First one
set table $FlowData
    plot f(x, 80.0, 0.25, 0.15)
unset table
# Second one
set table $PressureData
    plot f(x, 35.0, 0.75, 0.20)
unset table
# ***** THE PLOTS *****
# Turning-on the multiplot mode to place both plots
set multiplot
    # ***** FIRST PLOT SETTINGS *****
    set ylabel "Flow [l/min]"
    set yrange [-10:120]
    set mytics 4
    # Fist plot itself
    plot $FlowData axes x1y1 w l ls 1 lw 2
    # ***** SECOND PLOT SETTINGS *****
    # Remove previous customizations
    unset tics
    unset xlabel
    unset ytics
    unset ylabel
    # New customizations
    set border 8 ls 2
    set y2label "Pressure [mbar]" tc ls 2
    set y2range [-5:60]
    set y2tics tc ls 2
    set my2tics 4 
    # Labels
    set label "Compliance           : 15 [ml/mbar]"    at 0.95,100.0 offset 0, 0
    set label "Resistance           :  5 [mbar/l/sec]" at 0.95,100.0 offset 0,-1
    set label "PEEP                 :  5 [mbar]"       at 0.95,100.0 offset 0,-2
    set label "Inspiratory Pressure : 30 [mbar]"       at 0.95,100.0 offset 0,-3
    # Second plot itself
    plot $PressureData axes x1y2 w l ls 2 lw 2
unset multiplot
```

The result:
[image: Flow Pressure Time plot]

Comment: Thank you very much... I have a feeling that the original plot was made with ROOT.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the *default* look of `gnuplot`.
But gnuplot is quite customizable, and the looks depend on the capability of the output device (`terminal`) used and the libraries it was built with.

It is not uncommon to have your own `~/.gnuplot` or a site-wide `/usr/local/share/gnuplot/<version>/gnuplotrc`.
From the built-in help:

> When gnuplot is run, it first looks for a system-wide initialization file
>    `gnuplotrc`.  The location of this file is determined when the program is built
>    and is reported by `show loadpath`.  The program then looks in the user's HOME
>    directory for a file called `.gnuplot` on Unix-like systems or `GNUPLOT.INI` on
>    other systems.  (OS/2 will look for it in the directory named in
>    the environment variable `GNUPLOT`; Windows will use `APPDATA`).

Unless you are student that has to follow your institution's style guide, I would encourage you to develop your own style(s) based on the examples you can find online and your needs.

The information and examples available on [gnuplotting.org](http://www.gnuplotting.org/) is very valuable for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

By default font usually looks different and axis titles are centered.